# Inside a batch file, how can I tell whether a process is running?

Tags: windows, batch-file, process

I'd like to write a batch file that checks to see if a process is running, and takes one action if it is, and another action if it isn't.

I know I can use tasklist to list all running processes, but is there a simpler way to directly check on a specific process?

It seems like this should work, but it doesn't:

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe" /hn | MyTask
IF %MyTask%=="" GOTO DO_NOTHING
'do something here
:DO_NOTHING
```

**Using the solution provided by atzz, here is a complete working demo:**

**Edit: Simplified, and modified to work under both WinXP and Vista**

```
echo off

set process_1="firefox.exe"
set process_2="iexplore.exe"
set ignore_result=INFO:

for /f "usebackq" %%A in (`tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %process_1%"`) do if not %%A==%ignore_result% Exit
for /f "usebackq" %%B in (`tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %process_2%"`) do if not %%B==%ignore_result% Exit

start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.google.com
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use "for /f" construct to analyze program output.

```
set running=0
for /f "usebackq" %%T in (`tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe"`) do set running=1
```

Also, it's a good idea to stick a

```
setlocal EnableExtensions
```

at the begginning of your script, just in case if the user has it disabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

- PsList from Microsoft

http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/news/win2kcommands_0401.html#ps

- Cygwin (for ps)
- the resource kit (for ps.vbs)

http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/news/win2kcommands_0401.html#ps

- Powershell for get-process.